# Extensions not installed in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, extensions

I have the trial version of ArcGIS 10 (ArcEditor licence). The trial automatically installs and authorises all extensions for the trial period. However, in ArcMap I can only see Maplex, 3D Analyst and Spatial Analyst in my Extensions dialog box. When I check ArcGIS Administrator, it lists all the extensions as "authorised", but only the extensions I mentioned above as "installed". The others are "not installed". I am a bit confused about this, as the extensions are supposed to be automatically included as indicated [here](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/arcgis/eval10/evalhelp/index.cfm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah - just found the answer [here](http://gisatvassar.blogspot.com/2008/09/installation-steps-for-arcgis.html),by going to Control Panel and modifying the current ArcGIS 10 installation to include the extensions, although why they are not installed by default I do not understand.